# ImportError: couldn't find library

Tags: python, shared-libraries

I am encountering these errors frequently when I install python libraries and I'm wondering what I am doing wrong

the current example is the libchromaprint library
http://acoustid.org/chromaprint
I install it and everything, try to run the python example, get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/fpwav.py", line 7, in <module>
    import chromaprint
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/chromaprint/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>

ImportError: couldn't find libchromaprint
```

and then when I check:

```
find /usr/local/lib/libch*
/usr/local/lib/libchromaprint.so
/usr/local/lib/libchromaprint.so.0
/usr/local/lib/libchromaprint.so.0.1.3
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python does not use your usual library path. The chromaprint you're looking for should be somewhere like /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6.

From the python interpreter do:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

This will show you the directories python searches for a module.

Comment: Someone suggested this: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib  and it worked. Thank you anyway!